# Neo4j server plugin and complex type input

Tags: neo4j

I am using Neo4J v2.1.5 and creating a server plugin. Is it acceptable to use custom complex types as one of the inputs, as below?

```
@Name("postTweet")
@Description("Post a tweet")
@PluginTarget(Node.class)
public int postTweet(
    @Source Node source,
    @Description("Posting") @Parameter(name = "Posting", optional = false) final Posting posting) {
...
}
```

If not, what options do I have?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a finer grained control regarding input and output (including content types) refactor your server plugin into a [unmanaged extension](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html).